# There was an error creating the child process for this terminal

Tags: launcher, scripts, bashrc, cairo-dock

I am using Ubuntu since the version 10.04 and found it more friendly as compared to Windows. Right now I am using ' Precise 12.04`.  I have created many custom launchers for bash scripts, and never had any problem until yesterday.

I have installed a software suite which has multiple executables. The main executable `abaqus` is  located in `\opt\softwaresname` and is a symbolic link to the executable `abq610i` in  `/opt/softwaresname/executables/`.

The main exe `abaqus` requires some command-line arguments. I use the argument `cae`, (i.e. `abaqus cae`) but with another command to render the graphics in a better mode, hence the final call is:
`XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 abaqus cae`

I made an alias for this long  command in `.bash_rc` file as:

`alias abaquscae="XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 abaqus cae"`

Everything worked perfectly fine, as the alias runs the software.  Being a lazy champ, I thought of creating a Cairo-dock launcher for this. So I entered `abaquscae` in the box "command to launch on click" and checked "Run in a terminal". However to my dismay, upon click the launcher it gave an error::

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
Failed to execute child process "abaquscae" (No such file or directory)
```

Consequently I wrote a small bash script file "abaquscae.sh":

```
#!/bin/sh
"XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 abaqus cae"
```

and saved in, made it executable and upon running it in bash shell I again got the similar error, i.e. :

```
./abaquscae.sh: 2: ./abaquscae.sh: XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 abaqus cae: not found
```

Now I am totally lost, I have tried many tricks e.g.
1- removing commas in the bash script,
2- making it `dos2unix`,
3- using full path to the executable
but this script is not running through bash terminal.

## *PROBLEM:*

The command (as well as its alias) are work fine in the bash terminal, however when they are run through some other channel (e.g. scripts/launchers) the terminal miserably fails to recognize them :( ..

If any expert has advice/information about how to solve this problem, please share. I will be very thankful.

Comment: First of all I don't think the neither the dock's or the script's shell uses your `bash` profile. I think the best thing to do is to put your executable script in one of the standard binary folders (like `/usr/local/bin` for example), and make sure to put the correct permissions and ownership.

Comment: I have placed the script in  `/usr/local/bin/` , made it executable, and have set the permissions, but the error persists:  `/usr/local/bin/abaquscae.sh: 2: /usr/local/bin/abaquscae.sh: XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 abaqus cae: not found
`

Comment: Okay, what happens when you remove `XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1` from the script (i.e. just running `abaqus cae` like that from the script)? If it still complains about `abaqus`, make a symlink to it and put it in `/usr/local/bin/` with the right permissions. Good luck!

Comment: "1- removing commas in the bash script,", did you mean removing quotes? That line really shoudn't be quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the script should be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 /opt/softwaresname/abaqus cae
```

You can also create the launcher using the following command:

```
bash -c 'XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 /opt/softwaresname/abaqus cae'
```

Setting environment variables before the executable file name in a command line is a feature of CLI (Command Line Interface) shells. If you put `VARIABLE=value /path/to/executable` in a launcher, the program that reads the launcher (and effectively launch the executable) will try to find a file named "VARIABLE=value" and, of course, will fail.

That command launches `bash`, the default user shell in Ubuntu, and tell it to execute (the `-c` option) the string "XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 /opt/softwaresname/abaqus cae", so it will be interpreted like it is when you type that in the CLI.

Comment: the fist option didnt work , however the 2nd option i.e. the launcher command  `bash -c 'XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 /opt/softwaresname/abaqus cae'` worked like a charm .. TONS OF THANKS !!

Comment: I am really happy that the launcher is working now .. Would you please explain the science behind this method?

Comment: @MubeenShahid Answer updated.

Comment: You should still put a symlink to `/opt/softwaresname/abaqus` in `/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: @oaskamay: yes I had placed the symlink as you mentioned in the comment. Thanks for adding this valuable information :)

Comment: Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using `#!/bin/bash/` instead of `#!/bin/bash` (had an extra `/` at the end). The complaint was very similar but said, "child process not a directory". So helpful.